# How to stop users from accessing the backend source code running on server

Tags: server, permissions, lubuntu, root, administration

I wanted to distribute the server side code (Node.js)  to some of my users for hosting purpose, but at the same time I don't want any type of manipulation inside the code. So I have decided to use linux (ubuntu) server and rollout a simple distro by limiting the users not to read or write  on the  code. but later I am came to know that anyone having physical access to system can reset the root account.

Comment: Instead of manipulating your code, they could just host something else. If I interpret the question title and body correctly, it says "How to stop users from [manipulating] the backend [...] code running on [their] server", which simply is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

By design, someone having physical access to the machine can do anything. Even if you use a full disk encryption program like VeraCrypt, this protects only from someone who steals the disk/computer or tries to access it without knowledge of legitimate user. But the legitimate user must have the decryption password to be able to boot the system, so he is still able to do anything.

The only possibility is to remove the source code from the machine at all by using it in compiled form, if such possibility exists for Node.js. There are compilers for example for PHP (Zend Guard) but I don't know something similar exists for Node.js. You have to check.

Comment: thank you sir, I wanted to distribute the Linux Distro by locking the root user account and giving the guest user accounts , with a limited permission , so in this situation how I can prevent root password reset from a guest account, and If someone tries to reset the account , all the data should be wiped out. I am in a big problem , please help me .

Comment: @AadityaSrivastava What you want is not possible. You want to  protect your source code, so the answer is: no source code on the machine AT ALL. Compile the code and distribute the compiled version ONLY.